# Xcode 11 Can't Open Project/ Crashes

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, crash

I downloaded xcode 11 today because my phone somehow downloaded iOS13 and I needed to upgrade to hook it up.  Unfortunately, now when I try to open xcode on this project it crashes.

I feel like I have tried everything I have read- delete derived data, delete xcode and redownload (have even tried again with 10 and it won't open), delete xcshareddata, also tried turning off icloud.

No idea what else to try

```
Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 10B61
ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-14460.26/Xcode3Core/LegacyProjects/Frameworks/DevToolsCore/DevToolsCore/ProjectModel/DataModel/Containers/PBXContainerItemProxy.m:135
Details:  _containerPortal is NULL
Object:   <PBXContainerItemProxy: 0x7fe7a3309b00>
Method:   -remoteContainer
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fe79ef019d0>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints:   

Backtrace:
  0   -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1   _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2   _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3   -[PBXContainerItemProxy remoteContainer] (in DevToolsCore)
  4   -[PBXContainerItemProxy remoteContainerItem] (in DevToolsCore)
  5   -[PBXReferenceProxy sourceTree] (in DevToolsCore)
  6   -[PBXReference addNotifications] (in DevToolsCore)
  7   -[PBXReference awakeFromPListUnarchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
  8   -[PBXReferenceProxy awakeFromPListUnarchiver:] (in DevToolsCore)
  9   -[PBXPListUnarchiver decodeRootObject] (in DevToolsCore)
 10   +[PBXProject projectWithFile:errorHandler:readOnly:] (in DevToolsCore)
 11   -[PBXFileReference loadedContainer] (in DevToolsCore)
 12   -[PBXContainerItemProxy remoteContainer] (in DevToolsCore)
 13   -[PBXContainerItemProxy remoteContainerItem] (in DevToolsCore)
```

Comment: I understand you have both Xcode versions 10 and 11. May I ask which version of Xcode was downloaded directly from the app store? Not sure if you have tried this already, but I was reading on the Apple dev forum that one of the possible fixes was to delete the Xcode.app and install a fresh copy of Xcode 11 from scratch directly from the App store. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/117363

Comment: 11.1 and 10.1.  I have tried that many times unfortunately.

Comment: Not really a solution, but I deleted and reinstalled my xcode about 5 times and on the 5th time it started working again.  :/